# Holograms are apperaing in the application window unable to perform interaction and 3D hololgrams

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, openxr

I am trying to build a Hololens 2 application. I am using Unity 2021, MRTK 2.8.3. Before, I was creating applications for my research by cloning my Hololens2 profile, but now there is something openXR-related. Now, after performing all the same steps, my application opens in the window instead of holograms, and I am unable to perform interactions. I followed the instructions but always changed due to rapid changes. Please guide me where i am making mistake or where should i make changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/new-openxr-project-with-mrtk
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/new-openxr-project-without-mrtk

[image: mixed reality applicatoin]

Comment: The screenshot you provided contains some error messages, have you checked it? You can also find the log file in **Device Portal->System->File explorer->LocalAppData->[ProjectName]->TempState**. What is the specific version of unity you are using? Which MR-related packages are you using? You can also try the example scenes in the MRTK Examples package(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/running-example-scenes?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) to see if the same issue exists. And what do you mean by "but now there is something openXR-related"?